# How to assign an object array by index? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, initialization

Here is the constructor from my `Character` class :

```
Character(int, int, int, string, string, string, string, string, double, double, bool, bool);
```

And in the main function, here is how I have tried :

```
Character character[100];
character[0] = {777, 10, 5, "one", "type", "desc", "status", "knife", 10.0, 20.0, false, true};
character[1] = {707, 5, 10, "two", "type2", "desc2", "status", "knife", 15.0, 23.4, true, true};
```

The error state that it has no storage class or type specifier..

*EDIT**
Finally got it right using this :
p/s - Please provide a better solution if any. =/

```
Character character[100] = { character[0] = { 777, 10, 5, "one", "type", "desc", "status", "knife", 10.0, 20.0, false, true },
                             character[1] = { 707, 5, 10, "two", "type2", "desc2", "status", "gun", 15.0, 23.4, true, true },
                             character[2] = { 888, 7, 43, "three", "type3", "desc3", "status", "sword", 15.0, 23.4, false, false } };
```

Comment: It's assignment, not initialization.

Comment: I would have absolutely no idea what to pass into that constructor without looking. That's a really bad sign.

Comment: @user1071777 no, thats wrong

Comment: Looks like you have a [forward-declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration#Classes), but haven't included the actual header containing the class definition.

Comment: why don't people use std::vector?

Comment: @snurby77 Bad C++ tutorials or teachers, usually.

Comment: @snurby77 Didnt learn using vectors yet sorry..

Comment: @snurby77 Because teachers are still teaching so called "C/C++" fake language...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `operator=` properly defined, you can do this:

```
Character character[100];
character[0] = Character( 777, 10, 5, "one", "type", "desc", "status", "knife", 10.0, 20.0, false, true );
character[1] = Character( 707, 5, 10, "two", "type2", "desc2", "status", "knife", 15.0, 23.4, true, true );
```

Comment: What about this? Is it the same?

`Character character[100] = {character[0] = { 777, 10, 5, "one", "type", "desc", "status", "knife", 10.0, 20.0, false, true },
       character[1] = { 707, 5, 10, "two", "type2", "desc2", "status", "gun", 15.0, 23.4, true, true },
       character[2] = { 888, 7, 43, "three", "type3", "desc3", "status", "sword", 15.0, 23.4, false, false}};`

Comment: Tried your method. Not working. Still having errors.
[Image LINK](http://postimg.org/image/njrot6vjx/)

Comment: Do you have a constructor for Character that takes no arguments?  You'll need that to declare the array.  If you don't want to do that, I'd suggest using a vector.  Also, showing the actual error message would be helpful.

Comment: Yes I have the no argument constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you only mean to selectively initialize the elements in the array, `C99` has [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) which also seem to work in C++.

```
Character character[100] = {
    [0] = Character( 777, 10, 5, "one", "type", "desc", "status", "knife", 10.0, 20.0, false, true ),
    [1] = Character( 707, 5, 10, "two", "type2", "desc2", "status", "knife", 15.0, 23.4, true, true )
};
```

You must also have a default `Character` constructor for the rest of the elements.

However this feature [seems to not exist](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=550) in C++11 but gcc seems to handle it though (probably via an extension).

Comment: What is C99? Sorry I'm still new to all this.

Comment: @Student I was referring to the C99 standard.

Comment: Still not working with your method. What wrong am i doing. =/

http://postimg.org/image/pa57e6adb/

Comment: @Student: I had some misplaced brackets. I reedited my example. Please try again ...

Comment: As mentioned, this is **C99** not **C++xx**, you should not rely on this in C++.

Comment: @Gall Actually I think it's handled as a gcc extension in this case. So if using something else that gcc this will probably not going to work ...

Comment: @dragosht I don't think because of this : _In ISO C99 you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C90 mode as well. This extension is not implemented in GNU C++._

Comment: @dragosht Some compilers allow the use of some C99 features but a warning is clearly displayed. Obviously my comment was about the extension part.

Comment: @Gall Indeed: icc gets me this: error #2084: designator may not specify a non-POD (Plain Old Data) subobject